# Main method not found in class Base

Tags: java

```
class Base
{
   int x;
   int y;
   void show()
   {
      System.out.println(x);
      System.out.println(y);
   }
}
class Child extends Base
{
   void get(int x,int y)
   {
      this.x=x;
      this.y=y;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Child c1=new Child();
      c1.get(10,20);
      c1.show();
   }
}
```

Please correct this question.. I don't understand

Comment: obviously, you try to run class 'Base' which has no main method. what is the problem?

Comment: Try running `java Child` !

Comment: where i write main method ...please correct my question..i think any closing brasec creating error

Comment: @user2601676 You are partially correct. You have put the main method inside your child class. In order to run Base, the main method must be class Base.

Comment: yes...i try run java child and its working...but how to run class Base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the Base class, you should create a class Base (in a File Base.java, and delete the file Child.java before...) and write this inside it:

```
package my.stuff;

 class Child extends Base
{
   void get(int x,int y)
   {
      this.x=x;
      this.y=y;
   }


}

public class Base
{
   int x;
   int y;
   void show()
   {
      System.out.println(x);
      System.out.println(y);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Child c1=new Child();
      c1.get(10,20);
      c1.show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Main method not found in class Base

This is because `Base` doesn't not have a `main()` method; only `Child` does. Therefore, `java Base` won't work, whereas `java Child` will (assuming there are no other issues).

If you need to be able to run `java Base`, then `Base` has to have a `main()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The `main()` method is in the `Child` class, not in the `Base` class.

To fix, just run the program using `java Child` rather than `java Base`

Answer (score 1):

Your `Base` class has no main method.

Additionally, even if it did, you would not be able to override it as it's static.

Answer (score 1):

Not Main Method in Base Class. you write main method in Base Class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there can be only a single public Class in a single file and that must have the same name as the file name. When you execute a Java program you do it by `java MyClass`. Java interpreter will try to find the method with signature `public static void main(String arg)` in the specified Class file(MyClass in this case.)

Now in your code you seem to be calling `java Base` and java interpreter is not able to find the main() method in this Class(Base). So it is obvious you will get the Main method not found in class Base error.I suggest move your main() method to Base class.